# Cannot list tabs in a page using the page access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to list all the tabs of a page using the Graph Api Explorer. I am using a token generated by a page administrator. With that token I go to 128274006712/tabs and I can see a list of tabs for that application.

But when I obtain a page token, 128274006712?fields=access_token, and use that token to access the list of tabs, it just returns this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I could successfully delete a tab from that page using the same access token, so it clearly has at least delete permissions. And I could successfully add a tab to the page using another page access token obtained using the original user token.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The ?fields=access_token query is to **get** the page access token, and should be made with the user access token which has the `manage_pages` permission.

You can then use the page access token to access the page's installed tabs - is that not what you're doing?

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing. The weird thing is that I could add and remove tabs from a page using the page access token, but I could not list the tabs with the same token. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in another page with another user.

Comment: @PabloGraña sounds like a FB bug.